# arm-linux-gnueabi compiler options

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, objdump

I am using, **arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc** to compile C programs for ARM processor in Linux. However, I am not sure what is the default ARM mode for which it compiles.

For example, for the C code:

test.c

```
unsigned int main()
{
    return 0x1ffff;
}

arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o test test.c
```

now, when I look at the disassembly of main() function with objdump, I can see:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -d test

<main>:

    push    {r7}
    add r7, sp, #0
    movw    r3, #65535  ; 0xffff
    movt    r3, #1
    mov r0, r3
    mov sp, r7
    pop {r7}
    bx  lr
```

it appears that this is disassembly for Thumb mode of ARM (because of the push instruction).

How can I display the disassembly as follows:

```
      .sect ".text"
      .global _fn
_fn:  MOVW A1,#65535
      MOVT A1,#1

      BX LR
```

or this

```
      .sect ".text"
      .global _fn
_fn:  LDR A1, CON1
      BX LR

      .sect ".text"
      .align 4
CON1: .word 0x1ffff
```

I saw this example here:

http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/compiler/f/343/t/40580.aspx

however, I am unable to view the disassembly the way it is displayed there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[push](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Babefbce.html) doesn't necessarily tell you it is in thumb mode, in fact ARM's new assembly syntax called `unified assembly language` which means in most of the cases you can compile same code to `arm` or `thumb-2` instruction sets.

Other problem is that, you are compiling in `-O0` mode which adds some extra instructions for easy of debugability. Try `-O2` and you should get the instruction flow you want.

`gcc` with `-v` switch as in `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v` should show you how it is built, which also tells you the overall default options it uses when compiling your source code.

One last thing, targeted assembly sequence you mentioned uses `ATPCS` register naming scheme (check [objdump doc](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html) for information), it uses `a1` instead of `r0` for example. You can also get this by setting `disassembler-options` in `objdump` with `-M` switch. Like below;

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -O2 -o test test.c
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -M reg-names-special-atpcs -d test

test:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text.startup:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   f64f 70ff   movw    a1, #65535  ; 0xffff
   4:   f2c0 0001   movt    a1, #1
   8:   4770        bx  LR
   a:   bf00        nop
```

Another option is to get assembly output from `gcc` itself by using `-S` switch. Like below;

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -S test.c
```

then you should get a new file called `test.s` in the same folder. However I don't know if there is an option for you to set the register naming.

Comment: Thanks :) I have understood. Also, did you notice the second disassembly example I have mentioned above? In that case, instead of moving the value in the register, A1 it loads the value from the constant, CON1. Also, the different keywords like, .global, .align, .word are not mentioned in the disassembly.

Comment: I updated answer to add another way to generate assembly, where you can play to get a similar output to example you shared. Another thing is, you don't notice they mention TI's C/C++ compiler. They probably got the assembly output from that compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default is Thumb mode:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -S -mthumb test.c
```

The full ARM instructions can be generated using the -marm flag:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -S -marm test.c
```