# Program hang for cross-compiled ARM C program on X86_64

Tags: assembly, arm, cross-compiling, qemu

I try to cross-compile below C program on x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, using following
commands:

```
# gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --static -g leg.c
```

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int key1(){
    asm("mov r3, pc\n");
}
int key2(){
    asm(
    "push   {r6}\n"
    "add    r6, pc, $1\n"
    "bx r6\n"
    ".code   16\n"
    "mov    r3, pc\n"
    "add    r3, $0x4\n"
    "push   {r3}\n"
    "pop    {pc}\n"
    ".code  32\n"
    "pop    {r6}\n"
    );
}
int key3(){
    asm("mov r3, lr\n");
}
int main(){
    int key=0;
    printf("Daddy has very strong arm! : ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    if( (key1()+key2()+key3()) == key ){
        printf("Congratz!\n");
        int fd = open("flag", O_RDONLY);
        char buf[100];
        int r = read(fd, buf, 100);
        write(0, buf, r);
    }
    else{
        printf("I have strong leg :P\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*The source code comes from Problem Leg on [pwnable.kr](http://pwnable.kr/play.php). Local compilation won't help solve the problem, and here I am just trying to learn ARM assembly.*

The program hangs when I try to execute it after printing and asking input: `Daddy has very strong arm! : <input here>`.

After debugging the program, I find it happens when executing Line 4 ~ 5 in function `key2()`:

```
add r6, pc, $1
bx r6
```

The runtime behavior is:

```
; original assembly
    │0x104b0 <key2>          push   {r7}
    │0x104b2 <key2+2>        add    r7, sp, #0                 
    │0x104b4 <key2+4>        push   {r6}                          
    │0x104b6 <key2+6>        addw   r6, pc, #1                            
    │0x104ba <key2+10>       bx     r6          

; @0x104b4, before addw r6, pc, #1
r6             0x0      0
pc             0x104b6  0x104b6 <key2+6>

; @0x104b6, after addw r6, pc, #1
r6             0x104b9  66745
pc             0x104ba  0x104ba <key2+10>

; @0x104ba, after bx r6
r6             0x104b9  66745
pc             0x104b8  0x104b8 <key2+8>

; new assembly after bx r6
   |0x104b8 <key2+8>        lsls   r1, r0, #24                                          
   │0x104ba <key2+10>       bx     r6     <-- jumps back to 0x104b8, infinite loop
```

After checking other people's solution, they say the `add r6, pc, #1` and `bx r6` is for switch to Thumb mode from ARM mode. And the application on the server provided by [pwnable.kr](http://pwnable.kr) runs smoothly.

My question is why the cross-compiled program hangs? Is there I am doing wrong? If it is a bug, is it a bug from gcc doing cross-compilation, or a bug on qemu-arm-static?

Many thanks!

---

The command I used to debug:

```
# in Console #1
$ qemu-arm-static -g 10101 ./a.out

# in Console #2
$ gdb-multiarch -q
gdb> file a.out
gdb> target remote :10101
```

---

**Edit**

As @Jester suggests, the `key2` function is compiled in `Thumb` mode. Adding `-marm` as compilation option to enforce `ARM` mode. Problem solved. [More on arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328060/arm-linux-gnueabi-compiler-options)

Comment: Apparently you compiled the `key2` function as thumb code, when it was expected to be arm.

Comment: @Jester Yes, that seems to be the case. Do you know how should I compiled `key2` as arm code?

Comment: Try `-mno-thumb` (no idea what your gcc defaults to, mine defaults to arm)

Comment: @Jester Thank you very much. I did the trick using `-marm`. The gcc I use doesn't recognize `-mno-thumb`.